# Upper case beginnning letters of a domain using HTTP_HOST

Tags: domains, http, title, case-sensitive

For the past couple of months I've been thinking of a website I'd like to launch for a small community of people in my neighborhood. The concept is just a simple tag board to help the community know what's happening in their neighborhood. As a result, I've succeeded in that.

However as time passed more and more people sort of wanted to test the same concept on their communities but with their own branding domain. Which is why I've bought two domains and each point to the same website.

Thing is, I'd like to make it so that the website's URLs are capitalized in the beginning sentences like: "WisteriaLane.com" or "PlumasStreet.com"

I've succeeded in making the website's title use the following:

```
<?=str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);?>
```

However, when accessing the website, the domain name is lowercase and that means the title as well.

If anyone knows how to solve this, I'd be entirely grateful.

Comment: This is a programming question for Stackoverflow and off topic here. Everything before the dot in a URL is case insensitive and lower case so you can't take it directly from there. Someone on SO will help you adjust your code to do what you want but you need to specify what language that is.

Comment: Do you have the "CamelCased" names (which letters need to be capitalized) somewhere, or does the program have to guess what constitutes a word break? Also, I assume you're familiar with ucfirst()? Feel free to contact me directly (see profile)

Comment: @barrycarter - Sent you a request on google talk. :)

Comment: @Rob strange, i've been searching this forum and there's some questions that talk about the related topic (i.e. asking for support) and even then it doesn't answer my own.

Comment: Topic choices have changed over time. Some may have just slipped through.

Comment: @Ronnie I thought I approved it, but something may've gone wrong. Try again or email.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want the URL to have capitalized letters in the domain name, but you want to programmatically break apart the domain name into words and capitalize those for use in the title?

Comment: Just to clarify... I voted to migrate this question to StackOverflow (as programming related), not to close it "as unclear"!? I thought "...so that the website's URLs are capitalized in the beginning sentences" was pretty clear?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "automatically" capitalize (ie. CamelCase) a string of the form "wisterialane.com" without PHP having access to a database of words (which it doesn't have, unless you write this into the code yourself).

However, if your domains are a specific format with specific words, which they seem to be, then this simplifies the problem. eg. Capitalise the first letter and any of the words "lane", "street", etc.

For example:

#### PHP:

```
function toCamelCase($str) {
    // Words to convert/replace (ie. capitalise)
    $words = array (
        'www.' => '', // Special case
        'street' => 'Street',
        'lane' => 'Lane',
    );

    // Ensure all lowercase with uppercase first char
    $str = ucfirst(strtolower($str));

    // Convert any other words
    $str = str_replace(array_keys($words),array_values($words),$str);
    return $str;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<?=toCamelCase($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])?>
```

Comment: Since we are talking about domain names which all have to be registered ahead of time, I'd take the approach of just hard coding a list of them.